# Identical RAM won't work, second pair

Tags: memory, hardware-failure, post

- **Motherboard**: GIGABYTE Z690 AORUS Elite AX
- **RAM**: CORSAIR VENGEANCE DDR5 RAM 32GB (2x16GB) 5600MHz CL36 Intel XMP (CMK32GX5M2B5600C36)

I ordered another two, identical sticks of RAM last week, and they didn't work, even after I disabled XMP, took out the old sticks, and put the new ones in the exact same slots. No signal out to the monitor, just a steady red light on the motherboard so I couldn't even get to the BIOS.

I returned the sticks and got replacements, but I'm experiencing the same thing with the second pair. They're out now and the old sticks are back in and they still work fine.

What's the likelihood of getting two bad pairs in a row? I've never had RAM arrive DOA and I'd done this maybe 20 times before.

Before I do another return, I want to triple-check that they are indeed bad, but I don't know any other tests to perform other than to try them in a different box. And I don't have another PC that will take them at the moment.

---

**EDIT:** It turned out the RAM was fine; it was just going through an initial process of memory training. Leaving this up for reference, for some reason memory training took a *very* long time, even with just the two new sticks in.

Comment: Are you sure the motherboard isn’t just doing memory training?

Comment: are the modules listed on your motherboard's HCL?

Comment: Did you bother to take any kind of ESD precautions? If not, then who knows what damage you have done.

Comment: Yes the memory is on the support list. Gave memory training an hour, might leave it overnight this evening.

Comment: @PJ7 Regardless of how you take my tone, the question remains, which you have not answered. If you did not take proper ESD precautions, you very well may have damaged 1 or more components.

Answer (score 0):

Bib has a valid point with static discharge, ram fries faster than you think with just your hand touching it. So in essence he is asking if you "emptied" yourself before opening the ram box?

It's not just what motherboard supports, but also CPU.
What is your cpu full name(ctrl+shift+esc), under CPU performance?